# A word or phrase to express "écrivain engagé", a committed writer?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for an English expression as I'd like to form a special interest group on the international level. In French, the expression is *écrivain engagé*.  This is along the lines of "literature of commitment" which is defined as follows:

> "Literature of commitment" is the act, for a writer or artist, to formulate commentary or criticism, even though he is supposed to write up a dissertation with beauty being the only objective, this commentary being a way to serve a human ideal. This concept is opposed to that of art being carried out solely for artistic purposes and mostly developed around the twentieth century.

I've come across "committed writer" but the hits on Google seem to indicate that it isn't used in the same fashion.  George Orwell is the kind of writer we're thinking of here.

Comment: "Propagandist" has the closest denotational meaning, although the connotation  is quite negative in English,.

Comment: @MarkBeadles I don't think “propagandist” is right, it's too strong (besides being pejorative). Maybe something about writing for a cause?

Comment: While [Britannica](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/343936/litterature-engagee) suggests “literature of commitment” for *littérature engagée*, “committed writer” doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for lead. I'm looking for the expression as I'd like to form a special interest group on the international level. So the English should be used de facto. I can drop the reference to Victor Hugo if people wish :p .

Comment: @James Poulson: I think that's a somewhat waffly definition you've cited, and I don't recall "Literature of commitment" being a known term when I was getting my degree in English and French Language & Literature. But I do know **"committed writer"** was commonly used. More of French than English writers - George Orwell was a notable exception, but at the time we seemed to discuss his commitment to righting the wrongs in Spain more than his commitment to guarding against totalitarianism in Britain.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry about that. The source is a bit wordy and I didn't find anything more concise. Also thanks for the input. So it seems that commitment was or is used in a similar way but didn't catch on as much. George Orwell is the kind of writer we're thinking of here.

Comment: Another common description is *"writer and political activist"* (or *"social activist"*). But as my comment implied, in the rarefied world of academics and literature, explicitly socially committed writers aren't always regarded so highly as purely "artistic" writers (unless they're French, in which case we Brits are/were prepared to cut them a little more slack! :)

Comment: I deleted a slew of comments to reduce the confusion following the bouncing back and forth.  I also made some edits to try to make this question more topical for our site.  I will leave it for the community to decide if it should be reopened or if it needs more editing.

Comment: Are you looking for "apologist"?

Comment: @DavidWallace It's probably in the right direction. I'll look up the exact meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I read this question (over on French.SE), I immediately thought I would translate it with ***“a writer with a cause”***. Two things confirm this first intuition: 1. Gilles agrees, 2. [it is actually used](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748704099704576289251550643310.html) out there in the wild…

Comment: Brilliant. This is a great fit. Thank you very much :) .

Comment: It sounds good, I agree. Talking about [Sartre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Paul_Sartre), English Wikipedia translates the concept with **actively committed to causes**.  
"[Littérature engagée](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litt%C3%A9rature_engag%C3%A9e)" is a typically French concept, which does not mean it doesn't exist in literature in other languages, of course : Orwell, Brinks, to name a few.

Comment: Here's an update. I've launched a page on the world's most famous social network with the intention of creating a special interest group. Show support if you're registered on there and thanks again F'x :)

https://www.facebook.com/DevelopersWithACause

Comment: it seems the title of the newspaper article is a play on the famous James Dean movie "Rebel without a cause"

Answer (score 1):

***Engagé*** is used as an adjective in English. It was [Merriam-Webster word of the day](https://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day/engag%C3%A9-2013-01-24) on Jan 24, 2013. They define it as "committed to or supportive of a cause". They explain

> "Engagé" is the past participle of the French verb "engager," meaning "to engage." The French have used "engagé" since the 19th century to describe socially or politically active people. The term became particularly fashionable in the wake of World War II, when French writers, artists, and intellectuals felt it was increasingly important for them to take a stand on political or social issues and represent their attitudes in their art. By 1946, English speakers had adopted the word for their own politically relevant writing or art, and within a short time "engagé" was being used generally for any passionate commitment to a cause.

One example they give is: "Our next-door neighbor Michael, an *engagé* environmental activist, uses solar power to heat his home and drives a hybrid automobile."

It's not specific to writers, but nor is it in French.

Google Books finds various examples. Most seem to relate to Europe, where the notion of the public intellectual is more common:

> ...reaching out to new and young audiences, and bridging the gap between underground and high culture. This is the posture of the new-style engagé writer. (*Ethos and Narrative Interpretation: The Negotiation of Values in Fiction*, Liesbeth Korthals Altes, University of Nebraska Press, 2014)

> Politically engagé writing was struggling to establish itself in Switzerland. (*Ignazio Silone in Exile: Writing and Antifascism in Switzerland 1929–1944*, Deborah Holmes, Taylor & Francis, 2017)

Neither of these examples italicize the word, suggesting it is becoming part of the English lexicon.

Comment: It's listed (with no or merely domain caveats) in AHD, Collins, OALD.... (Collins restricts application to _male_ writers etc. Perhaps they expect the extra e when applied to females.)

Answer (score -1):

The Anglophone world is notoriously allergic to philosophy. Thus terms of philosophising about literature tend to be visible by their invisibility.

Hence in English, the term 'writer' is left unadorned with any fancy decoration and it's usually the context that determines what we mean by the term.

George Orwell wouldn't be usually introduced as a political writer but just a writer. The context of an article will tell you he writes about serious politics.